# Two different colors split within container, stretching to edges of screen?

Tags: html, css

Rather than explaining what I need, here's an image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYNcw.png

From the left side of the screen up to 220px in the container, the background needs to be one color, and the rest of the screen (from 220px to the right side of the screen) needs to be a different color.

How can I do this?

Here's what I have so far, without the background color stretching to the sides:

http://jsfiddle.net/a6L8hrot/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        2
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 970px;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 220px;
    background: lightgrey;
    float: left;
}

.content {
    width: 750px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D Except that I'm not seeking debugging help...

Comment: Well you haven't provided any code either. We're not here to write your code for you.

Comment: @Paulie_D http://jsfiddle.net/a6L8hrot/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this but, see if this works for you.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NewsletterPolls/j56tx3ek/)

```css
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .backgroundLeft, .container, .sidebar {
        border: 1px solid black; 
    }

    .backgroundLeft {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: gray;
    }
    .container {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 970px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: white;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 220px;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        background-color: gray;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">970
        <div class="sidebar">220</div>
    </div>
    <div class="backgroundLeft"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have a `div` element or a background image on the body, because you can't have a "split" background on just one element.

The approach I would recommend is the `div` element approach, as this is semantically correct.

CSS:

```
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    background: #ccc;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 220px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav></nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. It's even somewhat responsive if screen size is below 970px.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

aside{
  width:calc(50% - 265px); /* (970px/2)-220px=265px */
  height:100vh;
  background-color:lightgrey;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

article{
  width:calc(50% + 265px);
  height:100vh;
  background-color:white;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

nav{
  width:100%;
  max-width:220px;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:rgba(255,0,0,.3);
}

.content{
  width:100%;
  max-width:750px;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:rgba(255,0,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <nav></nav>
</aside>
<article>
  <div class="content"></div>
</article>
```